# Using anydate() with a user-created function

Tags: r, datetime, type-conversion, format

How come this worked for me...

```
#ks_train_1$deadline has unix data and time in int format
ks_train_1$deadline<- anydate(ks_train_1$deadline)
```

The script above works fine and returns just the date

but the following did not when I created my own function?

```
convert_to_date <- function(a,b,c,d) {
  #returns just the date
  c$d <- anydate(as.character(a$b))
}

convert_to_date(ks_train_1,deadline, ks_train_1,deadline)
```

I tried the following as well as suggested in the comment below and it did not work:

```
convert_to_date <- function(a,b,c,d) {
#returns just the date
c[[d]] <- anydate(as.character(a[[b]]))
}

convert_to_date(ks_train_1, "deadline", ks_train_1,"deadline")
```

Comment: rewrite it as `c[[d]] <- anydate(as.character(a[[b]]))` and pass `b` and `d` as strings.

Comment: although you don't need both `b`and `d`, just use `b`and do:  `c[[b]] <- anydate(as.character(a[[b]]))`

Comment: From [`?Extract`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Extract.html) (which includes `[[` and `$` operators): the *"main difference is that '$' does not allow computed indices"*, meaning `$` cannot be given a column name indirectly from within another variable. Since `b` is a `character` intended to indirectly tell you the name of your desired column, you must both (1) use `a[[b]]`, and (2) call it with `convert_to_date(ks_train_1, "deadline", ...)`.